# got exception when calling webservice in android?

Tags: java, android, json, web-services, rest

I got two to three execption when calling webservice from android apps. When i call the webservice from apps on 2.3.3(Emulator) version then i got exception like UnhostException , connectiontimeoutexception on 4.2.1(real device) version and working fine on 3.1 version, i don't know why this happen. I was trying to solve this exception from yesterday but solved yet, if any changes needed in the code then please suggest me.

In **LoginActivity** I call the method for making the http request

```
List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", login_tag));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", username));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", userpsw));
    JsonParserWebs jsonDataFromSrvr = new JsonParserWebs();
    String loginData = jsonDataFromSrvr.makeHttpReqToSrvr(loginUrl,"POST", params);
```

Following is the **JsonParserWebs** for calling webservice

```
public String makeHttpReqToSrvr(String url,String requestType,List<NameValuePair> params) {
Log.i(JsonParserWebs.class.getName(),"URL..."+url);
HttpEntity httpEntity=null;

//making http request
try {

    if (requestType == "GET") {

        //connection time out
        HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, 5000);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, 10000);

        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
        String paramString =URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url+"?"+paramString);



        HttpResponse httpResp = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
        httpEntity = httpResp.getEntity();

    }
    if (requestType == "POST") {

        //connection time out
        // From stackoverflow, I addes following three line but still got ConnectTimeoutException
        HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, 5000);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, 10000);

        HttpClient  httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

        HttpResponse httpResp = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        httpEntity = httpResp.getEntity();

    }

} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

try {

    json = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
    Log.v("JSON", "data"+json);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} 
// try parse the string to a JSON object

return json;
```

}

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Please post your stack trace.

Comment: Please post the logcat output for the crash (which is almost certainly due to an uncaught exception). 
From Eclipse, you can see the logcat output by opening the Logcat view.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use AsyncTask , otherwise it will crash!

Answer (score 0):

**1.** use AsyncTask when ever you use time consuming process other wise you will get network exception 
**2.** take internet permission in .mainfeast

Comment: i did used AsyncTask and wrote all permission in manifest file.